# Как идентифицировать кнопку при выводе запроса, php, mysqli

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

есть запрос из базы данных

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `gpid` FROM `groupid` WHERE `login` = '$login'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) { 
    $gr = $row['gpid'];
    $resul = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `$gr` WHERE `users` = '$login'");
    $resuk = $mysqli->query("SELECT `share` FROM `$gr` WHERE `id` = 1");
    $re = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resul);
    $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resuk) ;
    $shareall = $r['share'] * 100;
    $log = $re['users'];
    $share = $re['share'] * 100;
    $summa = $re['summa'];

    echo '<div><form method="POST" onclick="ch.js"  ><p>'.$log.' Ваш вклад : <input name="summau" type = "text" value="'.$summa.'" size="10"/>. Ваша доля состовляет : <input name="shareu" type = "text" value="'.$share.'" size="10"/>%.'.'     Общая готовность сойти на перон : <input name="shareal" type = "text" value="'.$shareall.'" size="10"/>%.     <input type="submit" value="Забрать" name="back"/></p></form></div>';
};
```

Дальше при нажатии на `input "Забрать"` нужно передать значение остальных инпутов в js (точнее чтобы js использовал значения именно тех инпутов, которые соответствуют данному `input "Забрать"`).(хотелось бы их потом передать через ajax запрос). Делал js `.click` через id, но он работает только с первой кнопкой, что ожидаемо, но до других способов и задач я пока не доходил.

Comment: ну так сделайте идентификаторы уникальными. например, `row-1`, `row-2`, etc. и обращайтесь к нужному при клике.

Comment: а как обращаться именно к той кнопке их же может быть 100, не писать же для каждой скрипт

Comment: ну так на родителя повесь обработчик js

Answer (score 0):

Вам следует добавить слушатель события ([`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)) на все нужные формы и при отправке ловить эти события, где уже и работать с самой формой.
Реализовать это можно примерно так:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('form'), form => {
        form.addEventListener('submit', ev => {
            ev.preventDefault();
            let formData = Array.from(ev.target.elements).map((e,i) => (e.name + "=" + e.value));
            alert(formData.join("&"));
        });
    });
});
```

Разберём этот код. Событие `DOMContentLoaded` вызывается, когда всё DOM дерево загружено и готово к работе. Внутри этого события мы добавляем на все наши формы.
При вызове события используется `.preventDefault`, чтобы отменить обычную отправку формы. Ниже в `formData` помещаются все элементы формы, разделённые впоследствии символом `&`.

Рабочий пример:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('form'), form => {
    form.addEventListener('submit', ev => {
      ev.preventDefault();
      let formData = Array.from(ev.target.elements).map((e, i) => (e.name + "=" + e.value));
      alert(formData.join("&"));
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="form-0">
  <p>
    Ваш вклад: <input name="summau" type="text" value="682" size="10" />. <br/> Ваша доля состовляет: <input name="shareu" type="text" value="853" size="10" />%.'.' <br/> Общая готовность сойти на перон: <input name="shareal" type="text" value="120" size="10"
    />%. <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Забрать" data-id="0" name="back" /></p>
</form>
<form method="POST" id="form-1">
  <p>
    Ваш вклад: <input name="summau" type="text" value="632" size="10" />. <br/> Ваша доля состовляет: <input name="shareu" type="text" value="438" size="10" />%.'.' <br/> Общая готовность сойти на перон: <input name="shareal" type="text" value="323" size="10"
    />%. <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Забрать" data-id="1" name="back" /></p>
</form>
<form method="POST" id="form-2">
  <p>
    Ваш вклад: <input name="summau" type="text" value="146" size="10" />. <br/> Ваша доля состовляет: <input name="shareu" type="text" value="762" size="10" />%.'.' <br/> Общая готовность сойти на перон: <input name="shareal" type="text" value="424" size="10"
    />%. <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Забрать" data-id="2" name="back" /></p>
</form>
<form method="POST" id="form-3">
  <p>
    Ваш вклад: <input name="summau" type="text" value="380" size="10" />. <br/> Ваша доля состовляет: <input name="shareu" type="text" value="210" size="10" />%.'.' <br/> Общая готовность сойти на перон: <input name="shareal" type="text" value="109" size="10"
    />%. <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Забрать" data-id="3" name="back" /></p>
</form>
<form method="POST" id="form-4">
  <p>
    Ваш вклад: <input name="summau" type="text" value="604" size="10" />. <br/> Ваша доля состовляет: <input name="shareu" type="text" value="416" size="10" />%.'.' <br/> Общая готовность сойти на перон: <input name="shareal" type="text" value="69" size="10"
    />%. <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Забрать" data-id="4" name="back" /></p>
</form>
<form method="POST" id="form-5">
  <p>
    Ваш вклад: <input name="summau" type="text" value="126" size="10" />. <br/> Ваша доля состовляет: <input name="shareu" type="text" value="145" size="10" />%.'.' <br/> Общая готовность сойти на перон: <input name="shareal" type="text" value="420" size="10"
    />%. <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Забрать" data-id="5" name="back" /></p>
</form>
<form method="POST" id="form-6">
  <p>
    Ваш вклад: <input name="summau" type="text" value="829" size="10" />. <br/> Ваша доля состовляет: <input name="shareu" type="text" value="884" size="10" />%.'.' <br/> Общая готовность сойти на перон: <input name="shareal" type="text" value="292" size="10"
    />%. <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Забрать" data-id="6" name="back" /></p>
</form>
```